# How to create a compound object in VBA?

Tags: vba

I cannot make my way through the Microsoft help, which is great provided you know what the answer is already, so I'm stuck.

Is it possible for me to create my own compound object (I assume that this is the term) such that, for example, the object could be a *person* and would have the following sub-classes:

- Firstname - String
- Surname - String
- Date of birth - Datetime
- Gender - String (M/F accepted)
- Height - Real number

Sorry if it seems like a very basic question (no pun intended) but I haven't used Visual Basic for a long time, and Microsoft Visual Basic was never my forté.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider using class modules instead of types. Types are fine, but they're limited in what they can do. I usually end up converting my types to classes as soon as I need some more function than a type can provide.

You could create a CPerson class with the properties you want. Now if you want to return a FullName property, you can write a Property Get to return it - something you can't do with a type.

```
Private mlPersonID As Long
Private msFirstName As String
Private msSurname As String
Private mdtDOB As Date
Private msGender As String
Private mdHeight As Double
Private mlParentPtr As Long

Public Property Let PersonID(ByVal lPersonID As Long): mlPersonID = lPersonID: End Property
Public Property Get PersonID() As Long: PersonID = mlPersonID: End Property
Public Property Let FirstName(ByVal sFirstName As String): msFirstName = sFirstName: End Property
Public Property Get FirstName() As String: FirstName = msFirstName: End Property
Public Property Let Surname(ByVal sSurname As String): msSurname = sSurname: End Property
Public Property Get Surname() As String: Surname = msSurname: End Property
Public Property Let DOB(ByVal dtDOB As Date): mdtDOB = dtDOB: End Property
Public Property Get DOB() As Date: DOB = mdtDOB: End Property
Public Property Let Gender(ByVal sGender As String): msGender = sGender: End Property
Public Property Get Gender() As String: Gender = msGender: End Property
Public Property Let Height(ByVal dHeight As Double): mdHeight = dHeight: End Property
Public Property Get Height() As Double: Height = mdHeight: End Property


Public Property Get FullName() As String

    FullName = Me.FirstName & Space(1) & Me.Surname

End Property
```

Then you can create a CPeople class to hold all of your CPerson instances.

```
Private mcolPeople As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mcolPeople = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set mcolPeople = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Set NewEnum = mcolPeople.[_NewEnum]
End Property

Public Sub Add(clsPerson As CPerson)
    If clsPerson.PersonID = 0 Then
        clsPerson.PersonID = Me.Count + 1
    End If

    mcolPeople.Add clsPerson, CStr(clsPerson.PersonID)
End Sub

Public Property Get Person(vItem As Variant) As CPerson
    Set Person = mcolPeople.Item(vItem)
End Property

Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = mcolPeople.Count
End Property


Public Property Get FilterByGender(ByVal sGender As String) As CPeople

    Dim clsReturn As CPeople
    Dim clsPerson As CPerson

    Set clsReturn = New CPeople

    For Each clsPerson In Me
        If clsPerson.Gender = sGender Then
            clsReturn.Add clsPerson
        End If
    Next clsPerson

    Set FilterByGender = clsReturn

End Property
```

With this class, you can For Each through all the instances (google custom class and NewEnum to see how to do that). You can also use a Property Get to return a subset of the CPerson instances (females in this case).

Now in a standard module, you can create a couple of CPerson instances, add them to your CPeople instance, filter them, and loop through them.

```
Public Sub FillPeople()

    Dim clsPerson As CPerson
    Dim clsPeople As CPeople
    Dim clsFemales As CPeople

    Set clsPeople = New CPeople

    Set clsPerson = New CPerson
    With clsPerson
        .FirstName = "Joe"
        .Surname = "Blow"
        .Gender = "M"
        .Height = 72
        .DOB = #1/1/1980#
    End With
    clsPeople.Add clsPerson

    Set clsPerson = New CPerson
    With clsPerson
        .FirstName = "Jane"
        .Surname = "Doe"
        .Gender = "F"
        .Height = 62
        .DOB = #1/1/1979#
    End With
    clsPeople.Add clsPerson

    Set clsFemales = clsPeople.FilterByGender("F")

    For Each clsPerson In clsFemales
        Debug.Print clsPerson.FullName
    Next clsPerson

End Sub
```

There's defintely more learning curve to creating classes, but it's worth it in my opinion.

Comment: You can also get around the issues with types by making a class which effectively is a type, but just has public member variables.

Comment: I know about types from C programming, but it never looked ANYTHING like this! As you say, a definite learning curve, but very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to use `TYPE` syntax, like this:

```
TYPE person

    Firstname As String
    Surname As String
    Date_of_birth As Date ' instead of Datetime
    Gender As String '(M/F accepted)
    Height As Single 'instead of Real number

END TYPE

Sub Test()
    Dim aTest As person
End Sub
```

Comment: Woah! That looks perfect! I assume that I can, for example, also create arrays of the compound object (assume I have a bus load of 30 people for example)? But this looks perfect!

Comment: @HugMyster in VBA you can also use `Class Module` ;).

Comment: OK, thanks! Two things I now need to look into, but both appreciated!